# Trying to return value from an object array with two same keys to a function. JS Rock paper scissors spock lizard game

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here's the const that contains the objects array:

```
const SELECTIONS = [{
    name: 'fire',
    emoji: '',
    beats: 'air',
    beats: 'lizard'
  },
  {
    name: 'water',
    emoji: '',
    beats: 'spock',
    beats: 'fire'

  },
  {
    name: 'air',
    emoji: '',
    beats: 'water',
    beats: 'lizard',
  },
  {
    name: 'lizard',
    emoji: '',
    beats: 'air',
    beats: 'spock',
  },
  {
    name: 'spock',
    emoji: '‍♂️',
    beats: 'fire',
    beats: 'water',
  },
];
```

Here's the function that returns the winner by comparing the property/key values of player and computer selection

```
function isWinner(selection, opponentSelection) {
    return selection.beats === opponentSelection.name
}
```

I added a pair to the object since I have taken a paper, rock and Scissors game and converted it to a paper, rock , Scissors, spock and lizard game.

Or at least I've tried...

I want the function to compare both the 'beats' . I have tried to rewrite the object and the function with no success.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment:  is the emoji for Spock. I don't know what that is... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think it is Dracula :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - it's Spock during the "Plak Tow" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are not going to work as you have them, as you can't have two properties with the same name. i.e. you can't have two `beats` properties on the same object because the second one will overwrite the first. e.g.

```
{
  name: 'fire',
  emoji: '',
  beats: 'air',
  beats: 'lizard'
}
```

Will actually be

```
{
  name: 'fire',
  emoji: '',
  beats: 'lizard'
}
```

Because `beats` is being set to `lizard` last.

To fix, why not put your `beats` as an `array` that way you can easily update your `isWinner` method to do what you want by using `includes` to see if the item is included in the `beats` `array`.

For example.

```js
const SELECTIONS = [{
    name: 'fire',
    emoji: '',
    beats: ['air', 'lizard']
  },
  {
    name: 'water',
    emoji: '',
    beats: ['spock', 'fire']

  },
  {
    name: 'air',
    emoji: '',
    beats: ['water', 'lizard']
  },
  {
    name: 'lizard',
    emoji: '',
    beats: ['air', 'spock']
  },
  {
    name: 'spock',
    emoji: '',
    beats: ['fire', 'water']
  },
];


function isWinner(selection, opponentSelection) {
  return selection.beats.includes(opponentSelection.name);
}

const fire = SELECTIONS[0];
const lizard = SELECTIONS[3];
const spock = SELECTIONS[4];

console.log(isWinner(fire, lizard)); // true
console.log(isWinner(lizard, fire)); // false
console.log(isWinner(lizard, spock)); // true
console.log(isWinner(spock, fire)); // true 

// etc...
```

Comment: This worked! I  tried to do that actually, but seeing your code I realized I failed when trying to the de const. I didn't do the square brackets and indexing. Great thanks!